# Do I need to copy command line arguments in assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, command-line-arguments

I work with fasm but maybe this question doesn't rely on assembly language version. Where is command line arguments string stored? Do I need to copy this string at program start or it is guaranteed to persist indefinitely? Can buffer overflows etc from my program overwrite original?

Comment: What architecture and operating system are you programming for?  The details vary, but usually the OS will place the command line arguments on the stack for your use.

Comment: OS: Win7 x64 ___

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Windows.  Perhaps someone else can help you.

Comment: *Can buffer overflows etc from my program overwrite original?* - if you got it, after this can be already all. need simply not have buffer overflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Command line arguments are part of the [process environment block (PEB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-rtl_user_process_parameters) and do not change after the process starts. You can access the command line via [`GetCommandLineW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew), and you can parse the arguments yourself. There also exists [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) which does some parsing for you.

The string data is in writable memory, so yes if you have buggy / insecure code that modifies one arg, an overflow in it could modify another one.

Comment: in general yes, in *PEB* in wide sense ( in `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` more exactly, but this nothing change). and yes, built-it windows dlls not change this. but nothing prevent another code (say by self) modify command line, if want